# What is wrong with this proof of wald's identity?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

When I  first saw the [wald's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation), I think proof is very simple just like below. But in my textbook or wikipedia page, the proof is much more complicated. So I think there's a huge mistake. What is wrong with my proof?

\begin{gather*}
E(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_\tau)
\\=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} E(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n)P(\tau=n)
\\=E(X_1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nP(\tau=n)
\\=E(X_1)E(\tau)
\end{gather*}

Comment: You are assuming that $E(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{\tau})$ exists. This is not obvious.

Comment: Why does the first "=" hold? Note that the expression on the first line equals $$E \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (X_1+\ldots+X_n) 1_{\{\tau=n\}} \right)$$ and you will need some result to justify that you can pull the infinite sum outside the expectation. (In particular, you need to know that the expectation is finite.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments for mistakes in the argument. However everything you have done can easily be justified if $X_i \geq 0$. By writing $X_i$ as $X_i^{+}-X_i^{-}$ you can get proof for the general case.

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm understand what I'm wrong!